# What can I use to attach bulky things to my keyring?

Tags: hardware, keys, fastener, every-day-carry

I want to attach a flat little multitool, a little earplug canister, and a little LED light to my keyring, but their bulk means the keyring won't lie relatively flattish.

So I put these bulkier items on small 1cm-diameter split keyrings, and slip those onto the keyring. This works great! The bulky stuff is a little farther away from the bulky parts of regular keys, so the key pile lies relatively flat. But after a while, the thin, fine-gauge wires that comprise those little keyrings come unraveled, snag on clothes and bags, and eventually drop what they're holding.

What are some alternatives?

- I haven't had great luck with the threaded, locking twisted wire keyrings. They're too big for what I'm looking for. (Haven't seen them smaller than 1.25" diameter)
- I don't like attaching a bunch of slightly larger keyrings to a carabiner. Because I just end up leaving stuff behind. I want the big bulky, single keyring, with a bunch of little things attached.

Comment: Use larger satellite keyrings, for added strength and tighter coil pressure, instead of the weak wire ones.

Comment: What about cable ties...?

Comment: Thanks @Chenmunka. My [original question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/are-there-small-split-keyrings-that-have-three-loops-instead-of-the-usual-two) was closed because the closer said it wasn't problem-focused enough. So I rewrote it here. The closer now says I should've edited my original question. Should I delete this question & move its contents to the original? The question I really want answered is: what are 3-looped split-keyrings called? You edited that out of this. How can I ask that in a way that's ok with Lifehacks? Sheesh new contribs are hard at Lifehacks.

Answer (score 2):

There are several shapes of carabiner like hooks and connectors on the market. I am personally fond of S shaped ones that are available from about 5 mm by 10 mm to about 40 by 80 mm, or an even wider range.
Out of door activity shops often stock these and other solutions.

The lifehack solution would be, for me at least, a piece of string closed with a good knot instead of your small key rings, or even the bigger one.

Answer (score 1):

First, buy several small standard spiral keyrings, about half-inch size. When you link 2 or more together, you get a short chain between your device and the main keyring. Now everything can pivot and lay flat. Also I use the smaller key rings to organize groups of keys on my main key ring.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a specific item, which you have never seen and wonder about what such a thing is called. It might not even exist as you imagine it.

Rather than look for that "three-lobed" item, let's go back to the problem. Maybe metal rings are not optimal for your daily carry. There are specialty clips, cords, and chains that are compatible with a single key ring. Are there accessories to a key ring that might be lighter, flexible, and tougher? Have you considered a strip of nylon with a hole in it for each item instead of a loop which takes more space, for example?

Can you attach a small leather bag or pouch to your belt - just large enough for your items? There are also very compact "runners belts" with space for your daily carry items.
[image: belt key pouch] [image: key rack]

For more ideas such as this "key rack," I would visit specialty .com sites such as "grainger," "keyring," or "carryology" where each shows a myriad of related small fastener-type items.
I would be surprised if there wasn't something at each that would work for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Stan. Really what I was trying to find out is if anyone makes keyrings such that the wire is looped around three times instead of just twice (or once in the case of "open jump rings"). But I appreciate your suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Pay close attention to the "three sites" I recommended! @EEE

Comment: Thank you, @Stan! I'm especially excited about carryology. (:

Answer (score 0):

The toughest combination of objects to accomplish what you wish is "heavy duty" or "Janitor's grade" split key rings — use one or more welded small chain links between the rings.

[image: flat wire split key rings]
In addition to round wire keyrings are flat-coiled key rings (shown).

Heavy-duty split key rings are available in stainless steel and also titanium.

Good luck